# Stata foreach loop for aggregating variables using egen total(var),by(level)

Tags: aggregation, stata

Say I have a bunch of farm data, reported at crop level (i.e. data is given for each crop).

Each crop observation belongs to a particular field, and each field belongs to a particular farm.  (Field and farm identification variables are included in the dataset.)

In Stata, I want to aggregate the crop level data to the field level, and then aggregate the field level data up to the farm level.

So for variable x, the basic command for aggregating from crop to field level is:

egen x_field=total(x_crop), by(farm,field)

Then for aggregating to farm level:

egen x_farm=total(x_field), by(farm)

I have a lot of variables I need to aggregate, so I would like to do this using a foreach loop, instead of repeating the same code for each suffix "_field", "_farm".  I would appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `egen` commands are the best way to do what you want:

```
foreach x of varlist var1-var99 {
  di "Processing variable `x'"
  egen `x'_field = total(`x'_crop), by(farm field)
  egen `x'_farm = total(`x'_field), by(farm)
}
```

The loop will go over every variable in the range of `var1` to `var99`. Look at Stata help for variable lists if you want to define your `varlist` in a more sophisticated way.

Edit: there should be no comma in the `by()` field (thanks Nick).

Answer (score 0):

I think Fr.'s solution works well, but here's an alternative solution. Both are likely to be very fast, but this approach doesn't require an explicit loop, but internally Stata likely uses one.

`renvars` is from SJ (i.e., `findit renvars`) and this functionality is part of `rename` in Stata 12+.

```
sysuse auto, clear
order rep78 foreign make price

* by one category
tempfile auto_r
preserve
collapse (sum) price-gear_ratio, by(rep78)
renvars price-gear_ratio, postfix(_r)
save `auto_r'
restore

* by two categories
tempfile auto_rf
preserve
collapse (sum) price-gear_ratio, by(rep78 foreign)
renvars price-gear_ratio, postfix(_rf)
save `auto_rf'
restore

* merge back
merge m:1 rep78 using `auto_r', generate(merge_r)
merge m:1 rep78 foreign using `auto_rf', generate(merge_rf)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, there is no need for aggregation to be in two stages. You just need to aggregate each crop according to farm identifiers.

An analogue would be observations on people within counties within states in the US. If you want the state totals, you only need to work `by(state)`. To see this, imagine you throw away the county identifier. You have not discarded any information that you need.

In any case, be aware of `egen`'s `tag()` function designed to tag one and only one observation in a group.